# Optional enum parameter is falsy when provided

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function, `log` which takes an optional parameter `level` which is a value from the enum `Level`. They are defined like so:

```
enum Level {
    Debug,
    Information
}

const log = (message: string, level?: Level) => {
    if (!level) {
        console.warn("The `level` parameter of `log` will no longer be optional in version 1.0.0");
        console.log(message);
        return;
    }

    console.log(Level[level] + ": " + message);
};
```

As you can see, I am checking if `level` is falsy because I want to log a warning message if they do not provide it.

This behaves correctly when I call the function like so:

```
log("some log message"); // logs the warning
```

It also behaves correctly if I use `Level.Information`, but if I call the function with `Level.Debug`, I get the warning message.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `Level.Debug` equals 0, which is falsy. Enums are just integers, starting from 0. You should check for undefined/null explicitely. `level == null`

Answer (score 1):

The "falsy" check checks a number of things. To name a few, it checks:

- Is the value `undefined`?
- Is the value `0`?

When the parameter isn't provided to your function (e.g. when you call `log("foo")`), `level` will be `undefined`, so your check behaves correctly.

However, at runtime, `Level` is defined like so:

```
{
    0: "Debug",
    1: "Information",
    Debug: 0,
    Information: 1
}
```

This means that when you call `log("foo", Level.Debug)` the function is actually executed as `log("foo", 0)`. This therefore passes your falsy check and logs the warning message.

To fix this, explicitly compare against undefined:

```
if (level === undefined) {
    console.warn("The `level` parameter of `log` will no longer be optional in version 1.0.0");
    console.log(message);
    return;
}

console.log(Level[level] + ": " + message);
```

Comment: A better fix would be to define `Level` as `enum { Debug=1,  etc}` and keep the `if !level` check

Comment: @georg Why do you think that's better?

Comment: It's much simpler this way IMO.